# Check if list of objects single property value exists in Hashset

Tags: c#, hashset

I have a list of objects in which the objects have a Guid Id property.

I also have a Hashset containing a bunch of Guids.

What is the fastest way to check if each objects Guid in the list exists in the Hashset, and then update another property on the Object in the list if it does exist? I do have the ability to change the Hashset to a different data type if needed, but the list must remain the same.

Here's the classes/enumerable

```
public class Test
{
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public bool IsResponded {get; set;}
}

var clientResponses = new HashSet<Guid>();

var testRecords = new List<Test>();
```

This is what I currently am doing

```
  foreach (var test in testRecords)
    {
        if (clientResponses.Contains(test.Id))
            test.IsResponded = true;
    }
```

Comment: By "the fastest way" do you mean from a time-spent-coding point of view, or from an application performance one?

Comment: That seems like the best approach to me.  A better question would be what exactly are your performance requirements and does this meet them.  If it does there's no need to try to optimize it.

Comment: First of all you can write `test.IsResponded = clientResponses.Contains(test.Id)`. Apart from that I think this is the best possible solution.

Comment: @Toxantron That would represent a change in behaviour that looks like it might be undesirable.

Comment: @MK87, fastest performance.

Comment: @mameesh This looks pretty optimal to me from a performance perspective.

Comment: I am not sure if this will meet the requirements or not yet as the data volume is unknown, so I wanted to see if this was going to be the most efficient way given the information I know at this point.

Comment: Yes, assuming the count of the hashset is high in comparison with that of the list, then this is how I would approach the problem.

Comment: @spender You are right if there is other code. Given from the description he does a simple lookup, in that case behavior is identical.

Comment: In my opinion too, that code is well written, I can't see any further improvement.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so

```
foreach (var test in testRecords)
{
    if (clientResponses.Remove(test.Id))
        test.IsResponded = true;
}
```

Or, more briefly

```
foreach (var test in testRecords)
{
    test.IsResponded = clientResponses.Remove(test.Id);
}
```

Every found value is removed from the HashSet, so each next iteration will be faster. Of course, it's worth only for the very large volumes of data. And besides, it is necessary to recreate a HashSet.

Also you can try this optimization (it is assumed that the properties `IsResponded` are false by default)

```
foreach (var test in testRecords)
{
    if (clientResponses.Remove(test.Id))
    {
        test.IsResponded = true;
        if (clientResponses.Count == 0)
            break; // the remaining IsResponded values will remain unchanged 
    }
}
```

This approach is advantageous if the size of the `testRecords` collection significantly larger than the size of the HashSet and with high probability all values from the HashSet will coincide with the values in this collection. In the case of finding all, there is no reason to continue to iterate on the collection. So, break the loop.

Comment: You're destroying his HashSet for no real gain, and he could possibly need the HashSet after he is finished updating his list. As for performance considerations, Contains is already an O(1) operation on a HashSet. Further, Remove is an O(1) operation, so your statement that it should speed up after each removal is without real merit.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - I mentioned the need to recreate the HashSet. I agree that it would be beneficial only after a full match and removing all Id, after break of the loop.